# HTTP calls in loop in a meteor app stops after a few calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Trying to automate sending mails to a queue of email ids stored in collection email. I am trying meteor for the first time so please pardon my lack of understanding if I have any.

I am using the following code (on `isServer` ) :

```
Meteor.methods({
    'sendEmails': function () {
        this.unblock();
        Emails.find({status: "no"}).forEach(function (obj) {
            var result = Meteor.http.call("GET", "http://someapidomain/email.php?email=" + obj.email);
            console.log(result.content);
        });
    }
});
```

This code is called at `Meteor.startup`. 
When this app is run, api is called and i get the results for 13 emails, sometimes for 5 emails, sometimes 2 emails and then nothing happens. Please help.

Let me know if more detail is required.

Comment: have you tried to add a time interval in your loop? It could be your mail provider limitations at fault. I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: There is no such limitation at the mail provider's end. Actually that api just returns a text (for testing) - "Mail sent successfully" and does nothing. And how to add time interval?

Comment: I would try it, it doesn't cost anything. It could be a time-out issue at any level and you can check it easily. You can add a time interval using: `Meteor.setInterval(function () {//send one mail}, 500)`

Comment: It did work with setInterval but only it did was increase the no of api calls after which it stops. It has increased to 15-21.

Comment: So I guess you have your answer. Increase the interval until you can make all your calls

Comment: But that's not the way it is supposed to be. There must be ways in which we can automate API calls or start a failover if it stops.

Comment: I understand your frustration. See it pragmatically: it is not so much about using the interval trick to achieve your feature in production, you just use it to make sure that the *only* thing preventing your batch to be sent is a time-out somewhere. Once you are sure of that (i.e. you can achieve the sending with a proper interval), you get two things, a quick and dirty workaround for your issue and the certitude that it is related to the frequency of the sending. From there, you have more info to try something.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing

```
Emails.find({status: "no"}).fetch().forEach(...)
```

Note the `fetch()` in the chain, which ensures that all Mongo communication has completed prior to doing HTTP calls. `find()` alone returns a reactive cursor, which means you're mixing Mongo activity and HTTP activity which might not be playing nicely - just a theory.

Reference: http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-find

Comment: well, i tried with no luck. It behaves differently on different machines and on different internet connections. Still stops after random no of api calls.